# Duplo-S em: milissegundo, microssegundo, nanossegundo

Tags: ortografia

Por que milissegundo, microssegundo, nanossegundo e provavelmente outras palavras para representar outras resoluções de tempo em frações de segundo são grafadas com duplo-S (ss)?

Comment: Para manter o som /s/, pois um único s entre vogais lê-se /z/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com o [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](http://portal.mec.gov.br/arquivos/pdf/acordoortografico.pdf), consignado por múltiplas repúblicas falantes de português (inclusos Brasil e Portugal), em sua segunda cláusula da base XVI [página 19], item a, não se emprega hífen:

> Nas formações em que o prefixo ou falso prefixo termina em vogal e o
>   segundo elemento começa por r ou s, devendo estas consoantes
>   duplicar-se, prática aliás já generalizada em palavras deste tipo
>   pertencentes aos domínios científico e técnico. Assim: antirreligioso,
>   antissemita, contrarregra, contrassenha, cosseno, extrarregular,
>   infrassom, minissaia, tal como hiorritmo, hiossatélite.
>   eletrossiderurgia, microssistema, microrradiografia.

Portanto, por convenção, quando uma palavra composta possuir ‘*s/r*’ ou **vogal** no fim de um componente e ‘*s/r*’ no início do subsequente, ou seja duplo ‘*s*’ ou ‘*r*’ ou “vogal + r/s” na conexão dos morfemas, deve-se ligá-los sem hífen, formando “***xxxxssyyy***” em vez “***xxxxs-syyy***”.

Ainda assim, qualquer falante minimamente fluente na língua entenderá se for empregado o uso antigo, com hífen; e configurar-se-ia um erro de norma culta negligenciável se não em documentos altamente formais.